# How to insert Tensor second order notation in libreOffice Math?

Tags: libreoffice

How to put double bar over a character in libreoffice math 5. As we use in second order tensors.

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in LibreOffice 5, it appears to be possible simply by nesting the `overline` command:

[image: LibreOffice Math]